# I cannot set different colors for my breeds

Tags: colors, netlogo

If i run this code several times on Netlogo, sometimes I get one green and two reds, and sometimes three reds, is it a bug or what is wrong with the code?

```
breed [greens a-green]
breed [reds a-red]

to setup 
clear-all
create-greens 1
ask greens[set color green setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
create-reds 2
ask reds [ set color red setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
reset-ticks
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code- I just ran a slightly simplified version 10000 times and had no instances where there were any other counts than 1 green and 2 red. Try this slightly modified version of your setup:

```
breed [greens a-green]
breed [reds a-red]

globals [ green-count red-count ]

to setup 
  create-greens 1 [
    set color green 
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  create-reds 2 [
    set color red 
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end
```

And to run that several times and track the count of each color:

```
to colors-check
  ca
  set green-count []
  set red-count []
  repeat 10000 [
    ask turtles [ die ]
    setup
    set green-count lput count turtles with [ color = green ] green-count
    set red-count lput count turtles with [ color = red ] red-count
  ]
  print word "Green counts recorded: " remove-duplicates green-count
  print word "Red counts recorded: " remove-duplicates red-count
  reset-ticks
end
```

The output for me is:

```
Green counts recorded: [1]
Red counts recorded: [2]
```

which tells me that for all of those 10000 reps the color counts were as expected (otherwise you would see other numbers when removing duplicates). Perhaps there is some other command run after your setup?

Comment: After running your code, I get the same as you, I also noticed that even if the color of the breed on the display is wrong, it obey the rules i set for that breed correctly (code not shown). So it must be an error of how my code is displayed on the screen I think.  Thanks!